Is this a Bernoulli experiment?
In a volleyball tournament, two equally strong teams face each other. A match is considered won if one team wins three games. What is the probability that it will be over after three, four or five games?
I believe it is a Bernoulli chain since it's either winning or losing ($\frac12$, $\frac12$) and a team's performance doesn't change after winning or losing.

But I can't think of the parameters $n$, $k$ to make it work.

For the case of 3 I can make it work without a Bernoulli chain: Win three times in a row is $\left(\frac12\right)^3$ and then multiply by $2$ since there are $2$ teams. But what is the solution for $5$ games?

By "What is the probability that it will be over after three, four or five games?" as written, the answer is simply $1$ and no computations are needed !
If you want to know the separate probabilities for each of the three situations mentioned for each team, you need to use one of the many variations of the negative binomial distribution, viz for any particular player, to get $r$ successes in $n$ trials with a winning probability of $p,\;\;$i.e. $f(n,r,p)$
$P(X=n) =\large\binom{n-1}{r-1}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$
$P(X=3) =\large\binom22 (\frac12)^3(\frac12)^0 = \frac18$
$P(X=4) = \large\binom32 (\frac12)^3(\frac12)^1 = \frac3{16}$
$P(X=5) = \large\binom42 (\frac12)^3(\frac12)^2 = \frac6{32}$
They add up to $\frac12$, as they should, simply by symmetry

The problem is essentially in three parts:
(1): What is the probability Team A wins 3 games in a row?
(2): What is the probability Team A wins 2 games out of the first 3 and then wins game 4?
(3): What is the probability Team A wins 2 games out of the first 4 and then wins game 5?
Each of these is a separate Binomial Distribution calculation.
Part of the formula is $nCr \cdot p^r \cdot (1-p)^{n-r}$
where $p= $ probability of the team winning,
n = total number of trials, which for B and C is 3 and 4 respectively,
r = number of successes.  For B and C this is 2 and 2.
Note: the last trial must be a win, so for each calculation multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$, the probability they win.
I will leave the calculations for others to fill-in-the-blanks (can update on request) but the answers are:
(1) $\frac{1}{8}$
(2) $\frac{3}{16}$
(3) $\frac{3}{16}$
Adding these together gives the probability of Team A winning in 3, 4 or 5 games as $\frac{16}{32}$.
By symmetry, this is the same as the probability of Team B winning in 3, 4 or 5 games.
So the probability of either team winning in 3, 4 or 5 games is $\frac{32}{32}=1$ as is expected by basic logic.
So to answer the original question the probability that either team takes 5 games to win is $2\times\frac{3}{16}=\frac{3}{8}$

Actually I'm interested in the calculation. And in my answer sheet fpr (3) meaning 5 games the answer is 3/16

Yes 3/16 for (3) is correct. The last statement of the answer shows that something must be wrong: the probability of either team winning in 3, 4 or 5 games should be 100%, not 15/16.

But is it a Bernoulli Experiment?

A Bernoulli trial only deals with a single trial.  The word you're looking for is a Binomial experiment or distribution.  Or actually a modified Binomial distribution, because once a teams gets three wins they stop playing.
https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/difference-between-bernoulli-binomial-distributions/#:~:text=As%20discussed%2C%20the%20Bernoulli%20distribution,a%2025%25%20probability%20of%20heads.

@TomekCzajka - well spotted. There is definitely an error in my answer, thanks for editing. I've made a small tweak in the LaTeX with one fraction and approved your edits.

@RedFive  So far we all missed the mistake "Adding these together gives the probability of Team A winning in 3, 4 or 5 games as $\frac{15}{32}$  It should be $\frac{16}{32}$  Note: The numerator is 16, in case it doesn't show up clearly in your font.  Editiing it in is a challenge, because edits require a minimum number of character changes.

Should be fixed now.
